# How to store a value from another component's data?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have two components, is there a way to store value from another component's data?

Here is **Create.vue**

```
<template>
    <div id="main">
        <Editor />
        //some codes here
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Editor from './_Create_Editor.vue'

export default {
    components: { Editor },
    data: () => ({
        text: ''
    }),
}
</script>
```

And here is the **_Create_Editor.vue**.

```
<template>
    //sample input for demonstration purposes
    <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="text"/>
</template>
```

---

The code above returns an error:

> Property or method "text" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

I want everytime I type the `data: text` from **Create.vue** has the value of it.

How can I possibly make this? Please help.

Comment: is there a way to inline component with another so that it can access the data of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using `$emit`.

Create.vue

```
<template>
    <div id="main">
        <Editor
            @edit={onChangeText}
        />
        //some codes here
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Editor from './_Create_Editor.vue'

export default {
    components: { Editor },
    data: () => ({
        text: ''
    }),
    methods: {
        onChangeText: function (value) {
            this.text = value
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

_Create_Editor.vue

```
<template>
    //sample input for demonstration purposes
    <input
        type="text"
        class="form-control"
        @change="onChange"
    />
</template>
<script>
export default {
    methods: {
        onChange: function (event) {
            this.$emit('edit', event.target.value)
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: that's what on my mind also Sir to use `$emit`, I want to ask is there a way to inline component with another for him to access the data?